# Get the logged in user as a var in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have the user name in this Razor Page on the Client.

Name: AssetList.Razor

```
@inject IAssetService AssetService
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider GetAuthenticationStateAsync


@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authstate = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authstate.User;
        var name = user.Identity.Name;

        if (name != null)
        {
            await AssetService.GetAssets();
        }
        
    }
}
```

I then get a list of data from the Database on the Client

Name : AssetService

```
namespace MyAssets.Client.Services.AssetService
{
    public class AssetService : IAssetService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _http;

        public AssetService(HttpClient http)
        {
            _http = http;
        }

        public List<Asset> Assets { get; set; } = new List<Asset>();

        public async Task GetAssets()
        {
            var result =
                await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<List<Asset>>>("api/asset");
            if (result != null && result.Data != null)
                Assets = result.Data;
        }
    }
}


namespace MyAssets.Server.Services.AssetService
{
    public class AssetService : IAssetService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public AssetService(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<Asset>>> GetAssetsAsync()
        {

            // Set the logged in user //
            //-------------------------

            var currentUserEmail = "currentLoggedinUser.com";

            // Get only Assets that the logged in users owns
            var response = new ServiceResponse<List<Asset>>
            {
                Data = await _context.Assets
                .Where(x => x.AssetOwner == currentUserEmail)
                .ToListAsync()
            };

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

If i manually set the var currentUserEmail = "currentLoggedinUser.com";
I can display only the assets for the current logged in user.

*I do not know how to set this variable in the Blazor Server?*

Answer (score 0):

see the following link to resolve this problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ebCVa6ueM0&t=33s

Also add this line to the Program.cs on the Server

builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();